aws_cdk.aws_ec2 RuntimeError: target.attachToApplicationTargetGroup is not a function
# 创建负载均衡器
load_balancer = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(self, "MyLoadBalancer",
            vpc=vpc,
            internet_facing=True,
            load_balancer_name="my-load-balancer"
        )

        # 创建 Target Group1，并添加 EC2 实例1
target_group1 = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(self, "MyTargetGroup1",
            vpc=vpc,
            port=80,
            targets=[ec2_instance1],
            target_group_name="my-target-group1"
        )

# 创建 Target Group2，并添加 EC2 实例2
target_group2 = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(self, "MyTargetGroup2",
            vpc=vpc,
            port=80,
            targets=[ec2_instance2],
            target_group_name="my-target-group2"
        )
# 添加 Listener，并将 Target Group1 和 Target Group2 关联
listener = load_balancer.add_listener("MyListener", port=80)
listener.add_targets("MyTargetGroup1", port=80, targets=[ec2_instance1])
listener.add_targets("MyTargetGroup2", port=80, targets=[ec2_instance2])



用aws_cdk创建一个loadbalancer 报
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError:
  TypeError: target.attachToApplicationTargetGroup is not a function
      at ApplicationTargetGroup.addTarget (C:\Users\LIUXIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-LGLn94\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-elasticloadbalancingv2\lib\alb\application-target-group.js:1:5027)
      at new ApplicationTargetGroup (C:\Users\LIUXIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-LGLn94\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-elasticloadbalancingv2\lib\alb\application-target-group.js:1:4518)
      at Kernel._Kernel_create (C:\Users\LIUXIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpinukwv\lib\program.js:10108:25)
      at Kernel.create (C:\Users\LIUXIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpinukwv\lib\program.js:9779:93)
      at KernelHost.processRequest (C:\Users\LIUXIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpinukwv\lib\program.js:11696:36)
      at KernelHost.run (C:\Users\LIUXIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpinukwv\lib\program.js:11656:22)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\LIUXIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjpinukwv\lib\program.js:11657:46)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\app.py", line 10, in <module>
    MyProjStack(app, "MyProjStack",
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 118, in __call__
    inst = super(JSIIMeta, cast(JSIIMeta, cls)).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\my_proj\my_proj_stack.py", line 80, in __init__
    target_group1 = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(self, "MyTargetGroup1",
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 118, in __call__
    inst = super(JSIIMeta, cast(JSIIMeta, cls)).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\aws_elasticloadbalancingv2\__init__.py", line 22635, in __init__
    jsii.create(self.__class__, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\__init__.py", line 334, in create
    response = self.provider.create(
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 365, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
  File "D:\Documents\pythonProject\aws\my_proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 342, in send
    raise RuntimeError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
RuntimeError: target.attachToApplicationTargetGroup is not a function

我怀疑是版本不对，但我查看了cdk的版本是2.136.0 应该是最新的。python中的aws-cdk-lib也是2.136

